# Setting header for date to lower SpamAssassin score

Tags: php, email, date, header, spamassassin

I have used a testing service (verifier.port25.com) to check what was happening when emails were getting sent from my PHP script.  For some reason they were ending up in my GMail spam folder even though SPF and DKIM are enabled.

It turns out that the SpamAssassin score was 5.3, thus above the 5.0 benchmark.  Below you can see why.  The biggest problem is that I have a domain with 12 letters in it (it seems crazy to me that I should be punished for this but apparently 12 letter domains are popular among spammers).  As I don't want to have to change my domain, it looks like the next best option is to set a header for the date, but I am not sure how to do this.  Could someone help with this?

> 1.0 MISSING_HEADERS        Missing To: header
>
> 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
>
> -0.5 BAYES_05               BODY: Bayes spam probability is 1 to 5%
>                              [score: 0.0345]
>
> -0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's
>                              domain
>
> 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid
>
> -0.1 DKIM_VALID             Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
>
> 1.4 MISSING_DATE           Missing Date: header
>
> 3.5 FROM_12LTRDOM          From a 12-letter domain

**Existing Array**

```
    $headers = array(
                    'From'          => $from,
                    'Return-Path'   => $sender,
                    'Subject'       => $subject
                    );
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding this to your headers.

```
"Date: ".date("r")."\r\n"
```

For the array:

```
$headers = array(
                'From'          => $from,
                'Return-Path'   => $sender,
                'Subject'       => $subject,
                'Date'  => date("r")
                );
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I format that to include it in the array I have for my headers?

Comment: What's your existing array for the headers?

Comment: I have added the existing array to the end of my question

Comment: Then it would be about the same. 'Date' => date("r")

Comment: I added the array to my answer.

Comment: While you're at it, you may want to add 'To' headers in the same way (if you're mass mailing, you can do an array_merge right in the send loop)

Comment: @aynber  Thanks, that has lowered my spam score now. I imagine there is nothing I can do about the 12-letter domain issue??

Comment: @arcyqwerty At the moment I simply have `$recipient = "****@gmail.com";` and then `$result = $mail->send($recipient, $headers, $body);`  How would I amend this to work with the 'To' headers? I am not mass mailing, just send one email at a time.

Comment: OK, I just added `'To'=> $recipient,` and now my spam score is even lower! Thanks